# Angular as-split with title of split

Tags: angular, split

I tried to add a "title" to my angular as-split-area, but the titles are always shown together and not aboth the as-split-are.

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 400px; background: yellow;">
  <as-split
    direction="vertical"
    useTransition="true"
    gutterSize="5"
  >
  <div>Title AAA</div>
    <as-split-area size="50">AAA</as-split-area>
    <div>Title BBB</div>
    <as-split-area size="50">BBB</as-split-area>
    <div>Title CCC</div>
    <as-split-area size="50">CCC</as-split-area>
    <div>Title DDD</div>
    <as-split-area size="">DDD</as-split-area>
  </as-split>
</div>
```

result looks like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p3DI.png)

the titles (div's) are always in section 1 and not as title for the as-split.

can anyone helpt me with this?

I didn't found any information about this on google.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the below code.

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 400px; background: yellow;">
  <as-split direction="vertical" [useTransition]="true"
    [gutterSize]="5">
    
    <as-split-area [size]="50"><div>Title AAA</div>AAA
</as-split-area>    
    <as-split-area [size]="50"> <div>Title BBB</div> BBB</as-split-area>
    <as-split-area [size]="50"> <div>Title CCC</div>CCC</as-split-area>
    <as-split-area [size]=""> <div>Title DDD</div>DDD</as-split-area>
  </as-split>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain why your code could fix this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).